# SQL sum and percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm pretty new to SQL and got a table like this:

| store_id | product_count |
| --- | --- |
| store1 | 50 |
| store1 | 30 |
| store2 | 20 |

I want to query for percentage of product_count for each store, so the result should be like:

| store_id | product_count_sum | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | 80 (50 + 30) | 80% |
| store2 | 20 | 20% |

I tried this code, but it didn't work (shows 0 on percentage):

```
SELECT
  tb1.store_id,
  SUM(tb1.product_count) AS product_count_sum,
  (sum(tb1.product_count) / (select sum(tb1.product_count) from tb1)) AS percentage
FROM tb1
GROUP BY tb1.store_id
;
```

Could anyone help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for window functions.  I prefer a ratio to a percentage.  That would be:

```
select store_id, sum(product_count),
       sum(product_count) * 1.0 / sum(sum(product_count)) over () as ratio
from t
group by store_id;
```

You can multiply by 100 to get a percentage.